# Shredding XML with unknown schema

Tags: sql-server, xml, openxml

I have to shred XML with unknown schema to a table. I don't know what elements there are in XML. And I am also not aware of XML format. In some cases XML data is Attribute centric and in some cases it is element centric.

For Example - 
I have two XML -

```
<Root>
   <Recorset>
       <RecordsetId>1</RecordsetId>
       <RecordsetName>name1</RecordsetName>
  </Recorset>
</Root>
```

AND

```
<Root>
     <Recorset RecordsetId="2" RecordsetName="name2"></Recorset>
</Root>
```

XML can have any other element/attributes. I need to capture the elements/attributes name and respective data using EDGE table produced from OPENXML.

What is the simplest way of doing this?

I need output in given format -

```
RecodrsetId   RecordsetName
1             Name1
2             Name2
```

Answer (score 3):

something like this?

```
select
    C.Name,
    C.Value
from @Data.nodes('//*') as T(C)
    outer apply (
        select
            T.C.value('local-name(.)', 'nvarchar(max)') as Name,
            T.C.value('(./text())[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') as Value
        union all
        select
            A.C.value('local-name(.)', 'nvarchar(max)') as Name,
            A.C.value('.', 'nvarchar(max)') as Value
        from T.C.nodes('@*') as A(C)
    ) as C
where C.Value is not null
```

**<kbd>[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/21196)</kbd>**

Comment: Thank you @Roman for your answer. But I could not find any way of creating pivot table from retrieved data. I have edited the question to mention expected output. Sorry, for not mentioning it before.

Comment: @AgentSQL so you want dynamic columns? I mean you want all elements/attributes fetched from xml and then create n columns dynamically? Or you want only RecordSetID, recordSetName?

Comment: Yes sir. I need to create n columns dynamically.

Comment: @AgentSQL and your XML could be anything? it could be tricky to do, especially to link nodes together in rows, if you don't have some knowledge about xml

Comment: Yes, it could be anything. I tried using relation on EDGE table produced from OPENXML but it requires a huge strings manipulations. And I can only work on one format(element centric or attribute centric) at a time.

Comment: Do you at least know the Root name?

Comment: Yes, I know that. Its same for all files.